# Access, Getting info from another table to display on one form already using a different table record source based on 3 Values

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Bit of a Roadblock I have hit wondering if someone can help me with.

Basically I have a 4 Tables

1. Uploaded_Data  (Customer Information caleld uploaded_data due to a ODBC connection related to getting data from Sage)
2. TaskList
3. TaskStatus
4. StaffMember

I have One form - TaskCreation

Task creation's source is TaskList Table,  And I want to have 3 combo boxes which will let me link a specific task to Customerinformation in Uploaded Data

What I am trying to accomplish is this

- 3 Combo Boxes linked to CustomerName, CustomerTelephone, and CustomerPostCode from Uploaded Data based on Customer Reference
- On TaskCreationForm, Once a user has selected a customer using the combo boxes, it will populate the Customer Reference into the specific Task Record for the task they are editing.
- On Task creation Form,  It will then show the customer info (name, address, phone number, postcode, email etc) from Uploaded_Data Table, into text boxes on the form itself for reference.
- When someone looks up a task (on a separate task list continuous form (Or on the Create/Edit Task form), they should be able to see the customer information, but also the task list table info.

Is this possible?  How would I actually make this happen?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to change your [`Customer Reference`] field in `TaskCreation` (the form) to a combo box.  You can display whatever would be most useful to the user, but generally you'd want to keep the unique key (presumably [customer reference] or [customer id]) as the linked column, and any additional columns will provide descriptive data to allow the use to make the best selection.  In the properties of the combo box be sure to appropriate update the `Column Count` and `Column Widths` -- '0' column width for the unique ID is probably the best practice assuming a numerical key.

Once the user selects this ID, you can populate additional non-linked textboxes by using something like `DLOOKUP`.

So for example I select 'Johnny Appleseed' from [`Customer Reference`], which has a unique customer reference # of 2132.

I have three other textboxes, `txtName`, `txtAddress` and `txtPhone`
These each have a control source set to a `DLOOKUP`.

E.g. txtname control source is set to `=DLOOKUP("[CustomerName]","Uploaded_Data","[Customer Reference]=" & [Customer Reference])`

Now when the user selects a cutomer name, customer info will populate in the form, though it's not linked.

Comment: That is fantastic,  However I am having a bit of trouble with the DLookup,  It gives me #error.

Does the criteria in that Dlookup string need to be set to the text box of the form?

Comment: Edit: I got it working but the text boxes using DLookup do not update once someone selects an item in the Combo Box?  I have to close and reopen the form to force this update?

Comment: Hi @Exxili, on the combo-box dropdown, add an 'After Update' event (e.g. after the user selects a customer).  In that procedure just add 'Me.Refresh' so that after a user selects a customer the form refreshes.

Comment: Yeah thats what i thought too but it keeps saying Access cannot find the object Me

Just want to thank you for your help with this!  --- Edit: Got it :) I just used a Macro to trigger the Form Refresh instead.  Seriously thank you Ryan!

Comment: Can I add a second combo box to search by Postcode, and then add an Or Statement in the DLookup to also update if "Postcode Combo Search box" is updated?